# No manual entry for any command

Tags: linux, redhat, manpage

I get the below response on trying to view manual for any command

> No manual entry for <<*command*>>

On `$ echo $MANPATH`, It says

> .:/usr/local/man:/usr/man

`$ echo $PATH` gives the following result

> /usr/local/bin:/mis/TREE/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/ucb:/proj/blade/tools/bin

and on `$MANPATH= man -w man` it says

> MANPATH=: Command not found.

What could be the issue? How to resolve this?

I am on Enterprise Linux 7 (Maipo).

Comment: do you have  `man-pages` installed? `yum install man-pages`

Answer (score 2):

if you have installed man-pages by

> sudo yum install man-pages

, then do

> sudo yum update